# How to rename variables dynamically in sas?

Tags: sas

I have a sas data set. In it i have some variables following a pattern

```
 -W 51 Sales
 -W 52 Sales
 -W 53 Sales
```

and so on.

Now i want to rename all of these variables dynamically such that **W 51** is replaced by starting date of that week and the new name becomes  - **5/2/2013 Sales**?

The reason i want to rename them is that i have sales data of all the 53 weeks in an year and the data set would be eassier for me to understand if i had the starting date of a week instead of W(week_no) Sales as a variable name

Is there any way i can do that in sas?

Comment: I understood all the words, but put together they don't make sense. Post a `proc print` of your data along with what your desired output is.

Comment: Are you sure you mean variables and not the content of variables? Since it is certainly not a good idea to disrespect V7 variable name restrictions.

Comment: Well i don't want to rename the content of the variables. Just the name of the variables

Comment: @user1946152: Why do you need it to be that way? I cannot imagine any use case where this is the best way to handle things. I suspect you want to do some kind or reporting, in which case it is better to have some more orthodox dataset(s) and do the magic during the report generation. Can you please expand a bit on your problem in your question. (through an edit? you have more flexibility with an edit to your answer than you have with a comment to an answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't want to rename your variables. You may think you do, but it'll just bite you eventually.

What you *can* do instead is give them descriptive labels. This can be done via `proc datasets`.

```
proc datasets library=<lib>;
    modify <dataset>;
    label <variable> '5/2/2013 sales';
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun lets assume you want to do this anyway -- Safest thing to do is just create a copy of the dataset for your output...

this code assumes your variable names are named like w1_sales and output names are going to be renamed to  03JAN2013_sale or something like that.

```
     data newDataSet; 
        set oldDataSet;

     %MACRO rename_vars(mdataset,year);
        data &mdataset.;
           set &mdataset.;
            %do i = 1 %to 53;
             %let weekStartDate = %sysfunc(intnx('week&i','01jan&year.'d,0));         %*returns the starting day of week(i) uses sunday as starting date.  If you want monday use 0.1 as last param;    
             %let weekstartDateFormatted =  %sysfunc(putn(&weekStartDate.,DATE.))     %*formats into ddMONyyy. substitute whatever format you want;
             rename w&i._Sale = &weekstartDateFormatted ._SALES;   
            %end;
          run;
    %MEND rename_vars;

    %rename_vars(newDataSet,2013);
```

I don't have time to test this right now, so sommebody let me know if I screwed it up somewhere.  This should at least get you going though.   Or you can send me or post some code to read a small sample dataset (obviously if this is possible without having to share some proprietary info.  You might have to genericize it a bit)  with those vars like that and I'll debug it.